# package not found on internal pypi index

Tags: python, pypi

I have a private package `mypackage` hosted on an internal pypi repo. When I try to install it I get

```
$ pip install mypackage

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://internal.com/repository/pipy-internal/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mypackage (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mypackage
```

I can see the package on the internal nexus. This is the folder structure

```
| internal.com/repository/pipy-internal/
| -- mypackage
| ---- 0.1.0
| ------- mypackage-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

This is my `~/.config/pip/pip.conf` (I am on ubuntu 18.04)

```
[global]
extra-index-url = https://internal.com/repository/pipy-internal/
trusted-host = pypi.org
               internal.com
```

The internal repo needs login credentials which I stored in `~/.netrc`

```
machine internal.com
   login myuser
   password mypassword
```

Installing other python packages (from pypi.org) works fine.

***EDIT***

When I run the `pip install` with `--verbose` I see that pip expects a file directly under the directory `internal.com/repository/pipy-internal/mypackage/` (probably the `.whl` file). But in my case there is an additional version folder (`0.1.0`). This folder structure is created by twine though

```
twine upload -r nexus --config-file $HOME/.pypirc  dist/*.whl
 Uploading distributions to https://internal.com/repository/pipy-internal/
 Uploading mypackage-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
 100%|██████████| 4.05k/4.05k [00:00<00:00, 12.2kB/s]
```

Comment: Do you really call it `pipy` instead of `pypi`?

Comment: @tripleee is that important?

Comment: If it's a typo and the real server's name is correctly spelled then yes; otherwise no, just a curiosity.